# How to use peek () with filter () java8?

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

I have a `LinkedHashMap`.

```
sorted:{0=[1, 2], 5=[4, 3], 1=[2, 0, 3], 2=[4, 0, 1], 3=[4, 5, 1], 4=[5, 2, 3]}
```

I tried filtering the values of each key based on its size. For example for the entry `2=[4, 0, 1]`, I need to filter the values such that the key should only have values whose size is greater than or equal to (`>=`) it

Consider `2=[4, 1]`: since `0` has only two elements, we remove it. 4 and 1 have three elements which is equal to the size of 2, so we keep it.

The final output should be :

```
nodes_withHighDegreee :{0=[1, 2], 5=[4, 3], 1=[2, 3], 2=[4, 1], 3=[4, 1], 4=[2, 3]}
```

I tried :

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> nodes_withHighDegree = sorted.entrySet().stream()
                .peek(e -> e.getValue().filter((a,b)-> map.get(a).size() >= map.get(b).size()))
                .collect(LinkedHashMap::new, (m, e) -> m.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()), (m0, m1) -> m0.putAll(m1));
System.out.println("After sort" + nodes_withHighDegree);
```

How to use filter function here?

Comment: Note that a single pass will not be enough. Since the number of elements in a key can decrease, you will have to check again.

Comment: @tobias_k I am guessing the count should be based on the initial map.

Comment: @tobias_k I don't think you understood what is asked here. Maybe OP can clarify but what I understood was: let's take `4=[5, 2, 3]` which is of length `3` as example. in the initial map `5` is associated with a list of length `2` so we remove it (`2<3`); then `2` is associated with a list of length `3` so we keep it (`3>=3`), etc.

Comment: @Tunaki You are right, I did not understand it, but your interpretation seems to make sense.

Comment: @tobias_k For the key 5, the values will be retained 5: [4, 3 ] because the size of key " 4 " is 3. Since it has three values  5, 2, 3. (see initial mapping) Similarly, size of  key "3"  is also 3. both sizes are greater than size of  key "5". (since the size of key "5" is two  having two values 4,3) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it quite simply using [`Map.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-). Assuming the data is inside a `LinkedHashMap` called `sorted`:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> filtered = new LinkedHashMap<>(sorted);
filtered.replaceAll((k, v) -> v.stream()
                               .filter(i -> sorted.get(i).size() >= v.size())
                               .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Output:

```
{0=[1, 2], 5=[4, 3], 1=[2, 3], 2=[4, 1], 3=[4, 1], 4=[2, 3]}
```

This code creates a copy of the map to hold the filtered instance. Then it replaces each value by filtering it and only keeping the integers whose count have a greater value than the current count.

---

In your current approach, you are using `peek` to modify the value which is a bad practice. Quoting from its [API note](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-):

> This method exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline.

Comment: Thanks a lot:)   Is there any tutorial to learn stream functions? I couldn't find a proper material.

Comment: @priya Oracle has published [online turials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) that you can follow. Playing with the API and reading the documentation itself is also great for learning.

Comment: @priya: [Are](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description) [you](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html) [kidding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/)?